# Aussprache der Wörter rückwärts

Tags: pronunciation

Die Frage betrifft das Rückwärtssprechen, wie man es manchmal zur Belustigung macht. Es gibt auch Menschen, die die Gabe haben, jedes beliebige Wort korrekt rückwärts auszusprechen, ohne nachzudenken.

Die Frage betrifft die Aussprache von Buchstabenkombinationen, die zusammen neue Laute ergeben. Spricht man die Wörter im Deutschen rückwärts phonetisch oder buchstabenbasiert aus?

Wie würde man **oder** aussprechen? [redo] oder eher [ɐdo]?

Bei **Hühnchen** eher [nɛçnhy:] oder [nəçny:h] usw.?

Dass man z.B. *sch* als [ʃ] weiterhin ausspricht, dürfte klar sein (Marsch → [ʃram]). Die Frage bezieht sich also hauptsächlich auf Laute, die aufgrund ihrer Stellung die Aussprache verändern, wie das Schwa-E, das stumme H u.Ä.

Comment: In der Grundschulzeit war das Rückwärtssprechen unter uns zeitweise ziemlich weit entwickelt, und es beruhte eindeutig auf Lauten, nicht auf Buchstaben. Daß dabei "unmögliche" Cluster z.B. wegen Ich-Laut und Ach-Laut entstehen, macht ja gerade den Reiz aus.

Comment: Opinionbased. Es gibt kein offizielles Rückwärtssprechen, also muss der, der ein solches initiiert, dazusagen, was er darunter versteht.

Comment: in diesem Zusammenhang evtl. auch interessant: a-Palindrom.npage.de

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wir sind eine zutiefst literale Gesellschaft. Praktisch alles, was wir über Sprache zu wissen glauben, basiert auf ihrer Verschriftung. 
Darum ist der naive Ansatz, den die meisten Deutschsprechenden verfolgen werden, wenn man sie bittet, ein Wort rückwärts zu sprechen, der buchstabenzentrierte. Da die meisten in der 1. Klasse einige Buchstabenkombinationen als (mindestens *ch* und *sch*) feste Fügungen kennengelernt haben, werden sie diese wahrscheinlich nicht auflösen, vor allem dann nicht, wenn sie das Wort nur rückwärts aussprechen, aber nicht lesen oder aufschreiben müssen. Bei den Diphthongen (v.a. *ai, au, äu, ei, eu*) und Dehnungsschreibungen (wie *ie, üh*) sowie einigen Buchstaben(kombinationen) (z.B. *z* -> /ts/ oder /st/, *ck* -> /k/ oder /kts/, *sp-* -> /ps/ oder /pʃ/) wird es unterschiedliche Ansätze und Ansichten geben.

Rückwärtslesen ist ein guter (aber allein nicht ausreichender) Test zum Bestimmen für Digraphen!

Das bisher Gesagte gilt für gelegentliche Sprachspiele, wo man also immer  /redo/ und am ehesten /nɛç.ny:/ hören wird. 
Wer – warum auch immer – tatsächlich so gut rückwärts sprechen will, dass eine rückwärts abgespielte Aufnahme verständlich ist, muss sich von der Schreibung ein gutes Stück lösen und sich auf die Phoneme konzentrieren. Da es im Deutschen wie in praktisch allen Sprachen positionale Beschränkungen der Phonemverteilung gibt, z.B. Auslautverhärtung und Verteilung von /s/, /z/ und /ʃ/, muss rückwärts anders gesprochen werden als vorwärts.